# How can i get device tilt?

Tags: android, rotation, sensors, android-sensors, sensor-fusion

I am trying to get device tilt (device rotation along y-axis but unfortunately i am unable to achieve my goal. I have tried a lot of stuff using TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD as a combined sensor (Sensor fusion). i have also followed [Motion Sensors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html)

**What i want?**

i want to get inclination of device (cell phone ) attached in a vehicle. Let say, i attached a device in a car and car is stationary. So inclination is 0 degrees.Lator on, when vehicle pass through under passes or flyovers, inclination should be accordingly.
I have tried to calculate this, here is my code:

```
...
...
    private static float ALPHA = 0.005f
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        edtAlpha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.alpha);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = mSensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magnetometer = mSensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        if (accelerometer == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oh  not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (magnetometer == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oh magnetometer not found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    protected float[] lowPass(float[] input, float[] output) {
        if (output == null)
            return input;
        String s = edtAlpha.getText().toString();
        if (s != null && s.length() > 0) {
            try {
                ALPHA = Float.valueOf(s);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                ALPHA = 0.005f;
            }
        } else {
            ALPHA = 0.005f;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            output[i] = output[i] + ALPHA * (input[i] - output[i]);
        }
        return output;
    }

    public int getRotation(final Activity activity) {
        int result = 1;
        Method mDefaultDisplay_getRotation;
        try {
            mDefaultDisplay_getRotation = Display.class.getMethod(
                    "getRotation", new Class[] {});
            Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                    .getDefaultDisplay();

            Object retObj = mDefaultDisplay_getRotation.invoke(display);
            if (retObj != null) {
                result = (Integer) retObj;
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Log.d(tag, "onSensorChanged");

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            gravSensorVals = lowPass(event.values.clone(), gravSensorVals);

        } else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            magSensorVals = lowPass(event.values.clone(), magSensorVals);
        }

        if (gravSensorVals != null && magSensorVals != null) {
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(RTmp, I, gravSensorVals,
                    magSensorVals);

            int rotation = getRotation(this);

            if (rotation == 1) {
                SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(RTmp, SensorManager.AXIS_X,
                        SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z, Rot);
            } else {
                SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(RTmp, SensorManager.AXIS_Y,
                        SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z, Rot);
            }

            SensorManager.getOrientation(Rot, results);

            float azimuth = (float) (((results[0] * 180) / Math.PI) + 180);
            float pitch = (float) (((results[1] * 180 / Math.PI)) + 90);
            float roll = (float) (((results[2] * 180 / Math.PI)));

            tv.setText("Azimuth : " + df.format(azimuth) + "\nPitch : "
                    + df.format(pitch) + "\nRoll : " + df.format(roll));
        }

        Log.d(tag, "Sensor type : " + event.sensor.getType());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }
...
...
```

**What the issue is with my code?**

When i rapidly accelerate /deaccelerate my car, angle goes rapidly increase /decrease but it shouldn't. In other words, when i accelerate/deaccelerate vehicle, there should not be any effect on angle.
i have also tried to follow these tutorials:
[Link 1](https://bitbucket.org/apacha/sensor-fusion-demo)
[Link 2](https://github.com/KEOpenSource/GyroscopeExplorer) etc.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should avoid using Accelerometer or Magnetometer data directly unless you REALLY know what the implications are and what data you receive from those sensors.

I personally recommend that you use the predefined `ROTATION_VECTOR` sensor which fuses Accelerometer, Magnetometer and Gyroscope in a Kalman-Filter. (see [this](https://bitbucket.org/apacha/sensor-fusion-demo/src/182a3034e5f7b305bf00356c9968a59b9a364d64/src/org/hitlabnz/sensor_fusion_demo/orientationProvider/RotationVectorProvider.java?at=master) how to obtain data from the ROTATION_VECTOR-sensor and [this](https://bitbucket.org/apacha/sensor-fusion-demo/src/182a3034e5f7b305bf00356c9968a59b9a364d64/src/org/hitlabnz/sensor_fusion_demo/CubeRenderer.java?at=master#cl-83) how to consume the data).

When you start from [this](https://bitbucket.org/apacha/sensor-fusion-demo/overview) project you can just access the quaternion and play around with it or with the rotation-matrix and apply the corresponding [conversion](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToEuler/) to get the euler angles of your device (the names are not always consistent but you are quite likely interested in the bank or attitude). 
One final remark: Note that euler-angles suffer from [gimbal lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198163/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-matrices-euler-angles-and-or-quaternions-f) (aka. "jumping" values).

Comment: First thank for answering my question. I have used your code in my sample application.I have used ImprovedOrientationSensor1Provider & ImprovedOrientationSensor2Provider from your code (including necessar classes).But i am getting variable results (angle) even my device (LG- Nexus 4) is laying stationary on table.
Here is ,How i am using your code:
Quaternion q = currentOrientationProvider.getQuaternion();
   float angle = (float) (2.0f * Math.acos(q.getW()) * 180.0f / Math.PI);
   Log.d("angle", String.valueOf(angle));
Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Here is output:
132.06401 ,
132.06432 ,
132.06334 ,
132.06345 ,
132.06252 ,
132.06252 ,
132.06168 ,
132.06107 ,
132.06134 ,
132.06215 ,
132.06207 ,
132.06268 ,
132.06332 ,
132.06416 ,
132.06346 ,
132.06425 ,
132.06326 ,
132.06314 ,
227.93698 ,
227.93661 ,
227.9361 ,
227.93614 ,
227.93663 ,
227.93794 ,
227.93845 ,
227.9378 ,
132.06181 ,
227.93822 ,
227.93892 ,
132.06259 ,
204.06075 ,
204.06076 ,
204.06076 ,
204.06076 ,
204.06076 ,
204.06078 ,
225.64037 ,
225.64124 ,
225.64375

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use the accelerometer and the magnetometer but not the gyroscopes, your method will fail when the device goes through rapid acceleration / deceleration. You can try to be overly clever and do some ad-hoc hack that may seem to rule out this particular failure mode you have discovered but I wouldn't even try it.

The true solution is to use gyroscopes as well. In my experience, that works pretty well.

What's wrong with the [`TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-rotate)?

Comment: Thanks Ali, Gyroscope gives just a change.It does not provide continuous change,e.g. vehicle moves through underpass ,then gyroscope will give you a sudden change in value.And also most of the devices have no Gyroscope. ROTATION_VACTOR : ROTATION_VACTOR is conserned with device rotation.Will be there any effect on Rotation Sensor of Acc/decell?.i think, it will have same effect

Comment: @MohammadImran Please re-read my answer. I am saying that you should use gyroscopes *as well.* So use accelerometer and magnetometer as before but augment it with the gyros. That's the only way to get the orientation reliably. Yes, acceleration and deceleration will *slightly* influence the results, hopefully you won't even notice it, thanks to the gyros. So, all in all, I am saying that the orientation sensor should be used (which presumably uses the accelerometer, magnetometer and the gyros).

Comment: Again Thanks, Can you please show here a sample code in your answer?  really appreciate your response.

Comment: @MohammadImran No, I don't do Android programming myself. I implemented sensor fusion and orientation tracking in C++ on the Shimmer2 platform. However, I am not familiar with the Android API. The point I am trying to make in my answer: I will need a device with gyroscopes and you will need to use the orientation sensor; then, depending on your definition of the tilt, you can then derive the mathematical formula for the tilt.

Comment: Can you please share mathematical formulas, here?

Comment: @MohammadImran Please re-read my previous comment. As I wrote: *depending on your definition of the tilt, you can then derive the mathematical formula for the tilt.* I don't know how you defined the tilt in your application, so I cannot give you a formula.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55812/discussion-between-mohammad-imran-and-ali).